# javascript oo programming syntax help for a noob

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm making my first stab at writing some oo style js.  When my page loads, it's executing my login() function twice and the event listener that I want to fire the login() isn't working at all.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is my code:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
var document = window.document,
    navigator = window.navigator,
    location = window.location;
//build the login button
var DA = {
    width : '70px',
    height : '20px',

    createLoginButton : function(){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.style.width = this.width;
        a.style.height = this.height;
        a.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = 'da_login_button';
        div.onclick = DA.login();
        div.innerHTML = "client login";
        div.style.width = this.width;
        div.style.height = this.height;
        div.style.backgroundColor = '#59724A';
        div.style.color = 'white';
        div.style.border = '4px solid #6B5D49';
        div.style.padding = '3px';
        div.style.textAlign = 'center';
        a.appendChild(div);
        return a;
    },

    //write the button to the dom
    writeLoginButton : function(){
        var dest = document.getElementById('digital_arborist_login');
        dest.style.width = this.width;
        dest.style.height = this.height;
        var theButton = DA.createLoginButton();
        dest.appendChild( theButton );
        theButton.addEventListener("click", DA.login(), false);
    },

    //detect ssl
    isSecure : function(){
        if (location.protocol === 'https:') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },

    // the login function
    login : function(){ 
        alert('href: '+location.href+'<br />protocol: '+location.protocol);
    },

};  
window.DA = DA; 
})( window )

// start the magic
DA.writeLoginButton();
```

[Here is the web page where I'm testing my code.](https://www.austintreeexperts.com/services/service_area.cfm)

Comment: When i check that page i'm getting an alert, what should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
theButton.addEventListener("click", DA.login(), false);
```

to:

```
theButton.addEventListener("click", DA.login, false);
```

and this:

```
div.onclick = DA.login();
```

to:

```
div.onclick = DA.login;
```

You want to assign the function itself as the callback in each case.  You are actually executing the function and assigning the result of the function call as the callback...  That is why your "login" method is running twice at startup and why your click events are not functioning properly.

You should also remove the `undefined` argument from the first line.  `undefined` is a keyword in javascript and I'm honestly surprised that you didn't get a syntax error from that.  It should look like:

```
(function(window) {
```

Comment: `undefined` may be a keyword, but most browsers let you assign a value to it.  Adding `undefined` to the parameter list makes sure it's really set to `undefined`.  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9Lv7Y/

Comment: This did the trick!  Thanks!  Also, I removed the div.onclick =  because I don't need two click handlers for the same button.

Comment: I used the undefined keyword simply as a process of copying jQuery.  I didn't know why I was doing it, now I do.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Keith: Yup, that's done to make sure global variables are what they should be.

Comment: @Rocket can you provide a link or some explanation to the inner workings of the syntax: (function(){})().  I've been googling and can't come up with much.

Comment: @Keith: That's called a "Self-Executing Anonymous Function".  Basically, you make a function, and then immediately call it.  This makes a new scope, so that stuff isn't making variables in the global scope.  I Googled a bit, and found this: http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/

Comment: @Rocket, thanks for the explanation of the `undefined` arg. Now I remember having seen that (probably years ago) in the jquery code. I was just assuming a typo!

Comment: @Prestaul: No problem.  JavaScript has some odd quirks like that :-P

Comment: @Rocket That article is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
theButton.addEventListener("click", DA.login(), false);
```

In this line change `DA.login()` to just `DA.login`.  When you do `DA.login()`, you're passing the *result* of the `login()` function (which is `undefined`) to the click handler, instead of the function itself.

It should be:

```
theButton.addEventListener("click", DA.login, false);
```

EDIT: `div.onclick = DA.login();` should be `div.onclick = DA.login;`, also.